# Highchart points not set to y asix

Tags: highcharts

I setting data to highchart with razor syntax like this :

```
series: [
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
                <text>
                    {
                        name: '@item.name',
                        data: [
                            @foreach (var item2 in item.finalChart)
                            {
                                @:[Date.parse("@item2.date1"), @item2.value],
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                </text>
        }
        ]
```

And here is executed code:

```
series: [                    
                    {
                        name: 'clicks6',
                        data: [
                                [Date.parse("04/03/2017"), 10],
                                [Date.parse("04/04/2017"), 45],
                        ]
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'clicks4',
                        data: [
                                [Date.parse("04/03/2017"), 28],
                                [Date.parse("04/04/2017"), 22],
                        ]
                    },

                    {
                        name: 'clicks8',
                        data: [
                                [Date.parse("04/03/2017"), 8],
                                [Date.parse("04/04/2017"), 35],
                                [Date.parse("04/05/2017"), 5],
                                [Date.parse("04/10/2017"), 0],
                        ]
                    },
        ]
```

As you can see in below points not adapted with `y` axis.

[image]

If I add another format of data this problem doesn't happend

```
series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  },{
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
}]
```

How can fix this issue? with some reasons I can't use another format of data.

UPDATE:
It is desired mode that I want:
[image]

Comment: can you add screen shot of  chart you want.

Comment: please see it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add `UTC` to each date input `Date.parse("04/03/2017" + ' UTC')`

   `@:[Date.parse("@item2.date1" + ' UTC'), @item2.value],`
2. xAxis will be

   `xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime',
       tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000  //this is for one day
     },`

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    zoomType: 'x'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
      'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Snow Depth'
    },

  },

  series: [{
      name: 'clicks6',
      data: [
        [Date.parse("04/03/2017" + ' UTC'), 10],
        [Date.parse("04/04/2017" + ' UTC'), 45],
      ]
    },

    {
      name: 'clicks4',
      data: [
        [Date.parse("04/03/2017" + ' UTC'), 28],
        [Date.parse("04/04/2017" + ' UTC'), 22],
      ]
    },

    {
      name: 'clicks8',
      data: [
        [Date.parse("04/03/2017" + ' UTC'), 8],
        [Date.parse("04/04/2017" + ' UTC'), 35],
        [Date.parse("04/05/2017" + ' UTC'), 5],
        [Date.parse("04/10/2017" + ' UTC'), 0],
      ]
    },
  ]


});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```